# TextView returning false

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerView with a viewholder in which I am trying to bind TextViews onto the holder. I have bound my ImageViews just fine, but my TextViews only display false.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BreadSliceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    /****************
     * User Icon *
     ****************/

    int userNameId = 0;
    userNameId = ViewHolderUtilities
            .getUserIcon(userNameId);

    holder.iconView.setImageResource(userNameId);

    /****************
     * User Name*
     ****************/

    int userName = 1;
    userName = ViewHolderUtilities
            .getUserName(userName);

    holder.userName.setText(userName);

    /****************
     * User Crumbs*
     ****************/

    int userCrumb = 2;
    userCrumb = ViewHolderUtilities
            .getUserCrumb(userCrumb);

    holder.numberOfCrumbs.setText(userCrumb);

    /****************
     * Total Distance*
     ****************/

    int totalDistance = 3;
    totalDistance = ViewHolderUtilities
            .getTotalDistance(totalDistance);

    holder.totalDistance.setText(totalDistance);
}
```

This is the Utilities class were I return Ids:

```
public class ViewHolderUtilities {
    public static int getUserIcon(int userId) {
        return R.drawable.man_stock;
    }

    public static int getUserCrumb() {
        return R.id.number_of_crumbs;
    }

    public static int getTotalDistance() {
        return R.id.total_distance;
    }

    public static int getUserName() {
        return R.id.user_name;
    }
}
```

This is the XML code for the TextViews:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:src="@drawable/man_stock" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/crumb_imageView"
    android:layout_width="12dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/number_of_crumbs"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/breadcrumbs_crumb" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_of_crumbs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_date_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_date_start_margin"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/user_icon"
    tools:text="@string/number_of_crumbs" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/number_of_crumbs"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:text="@string/user_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/total_distance"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/crumb_imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/number_of_crumbs"
    tools:text="@string/distance_traveled" />
```

And this is the portion of code where the views/images are set

```
 class BreadSliceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    final ImageView iconView;
    final ImageView crumbImageView;


    final TextView userName;
    final TextView numberOfCrumbs;
    final TextView totalDistance;


    BreadSliceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_icon);
        crumbImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.crumb_imageView);

        numberOfCrumbs = (TextView) view.findViewById(number_of_crumbs);
        userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        totalDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_distance);
```

Thanks for your time while looking this over. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: First: `ViewHolderUtilities` is not the correct one or used correctly.
Second: You return ids with it, not strings.
Third: Do the all `TextView` display the literal string `"false"`?

Comment: post your full adapter class

Comment: Yes, all the TextView display the literal string false. I think I understand why though. Thanks for your help